# Humidity not recording on wunderground upload API

Tags: python, wunderground

I'm using the wunderground API to upload data from a Sparkfun weathershield via a python script running on a raspberry Pi. Below is representative of my upload data - it appears to follow the upload API, but humidity is not being recorded.

https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?ID=KUTWESTJ##&PASSWORD=XXXXXXXX&winddir=158&windspeedmph=0.2&humdity=35&tempf=34.0&rainin=0.03&dailyrainin=0.03&baromin=33.93&dateutc=2016-12-05%2B23-44-23%0D%0A&softwaretype=RaspberryPi&action=updateraw&realtime=1&rtfreq=10

Anyone else seeing issues with the humidity value?

Comment: Seems to me there's a typo for `humidity`, as I see there `humdity`

Comment: Wow. That's embarrassing. Thanks @sal!